# WPF: Change visiable of Label when other control click

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I just go to WPF and have many problems, I very much like WPF and started working with it. I just make a design with WPF:

[image]

Now, I want when I click on label (icon with 3 line), then label without icon in sidebar will hide (can hide with animation).

Here my code:

Icon button:

```
<DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Left">
    <!-- Minimize Sidebar -->
    <Label Name="LblMinimizeSideBar" Style="{StaticResource FontAwesome}" Foreground="{DynamicResource MainColor}" FontSize="24" Margin="10 0 0 0" VerticalAlignment="Center" MouseLeftButtonDown="LblMinimizeSideBar_MouseLeftButtonDown">&#xf0c9;</Label>
</DockPanel>
```

Sidebar:

```
<StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Left" Width="80" Background="{DynamicResource MainColor}">
<ItemsControl Name="IcTodoList">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled}" Orientation="Vertical" Background="{Binding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Cursor="Hand">
                <Label Style="{StaticResource FontAwesome}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" Foreground="#FFF">
                    &#xf007;
                </Label>
                <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#FFF" Padding="0 0 0 10" Content="{Binding Title}"></Label>
                <StackPanel.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames  BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(StackPanel.Background).Color">
                                    <LinearColorKeyFrame Value="#DB1918" KeyTime="0:0:0.6"/>
                                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames  BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(StackPanel.Background).Color">
                                    <LinearColorKeyFrame Value="#FF5750" KeyTime="0:0:0.6"/>
                                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </StackPanel.Triggers>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
</StackPanel>
```

Any easy way to make this?

Thankyou very much!

Comment: first you should probably use a button for getting a click , second have you considered using code behind so you can use the name of the control you want and change visibility property in the click event

Comment: But Label I want hide haven't name, it in a itemscontrol, how to I can query to it?

Comment: in second Thought you can use an event trigger with target name

Comment: I'm sorry but It don't have name.

Comment: *you can always add a name

Comment: But I binding ItemsControl items dynamic and the property "Name" is not dynamic binding.

Comment: If the things in your ItemsControl are to be clicked on, then why not just make them buttons? You can then create a style for your button so that it has a label/icon/whatever, and just hook up a command so that a button click *does something*, even passing in parameter of the item that was clicked if you like.

Comment: @Mashton Here problem not Label or button. Here problem is I want when I click on label(button) then Label in item (StackPanel) in ItemsControl will be hide. But cause item of ItemsControl is dynamic binding, so I can't access to Label in item(StackPanel) in ItemsControl to hide/show it.

Comment: I have no idea what label you are talking about: what label are you trying to hide? `LblMinimizeSideBar` or one of the names that appear on your buttons in the left hand nav? If the latter, then what you are saying is that the name should only be shown for a selected item, which is the same behaviour as a `RadioButton`. In which case I'd base the items in that control on a RadioButton and give them a selected and unselected style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this in the label triggers to start animation in the items control

Example

```
<ItemsControl Name="TheItemYouWantToChange" />
```

in the view resources

```
 <!-- Begin the Storyboard -->
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click\MOUSEDOWN" SourceName="YOUR_LABLE\BUTTON_NAME">
      <BeginStoryboard Name="MyBeginStoryboard">
        <Storyboard >
          <DoubleAnimation 
            Storyboard.TargetName="TheItemYouWantToChange" 
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" 
            Duration="0:0:5" From="1" To="0" />
        </Storyboard>
      </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
```

you can use animation to change opacity and visibility 
for more info you can see : (the example is partly from there) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms744905(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Can I query my label in my ItemsControl:IcTodoList by ItemsControl:IcTodoList?

Comment: sorry, can you explain ?

Comment: I want only change visible of my second label in my StackPanel and my label is dynamic binding and it don't have name. How to I can get it (query to it)?

Comment: @SơnLê you can use the x:Name attribute to give a name to pretty much any object.

Comment: Seem Name attibute is not dynamic binding :(

Comment: Ok got it , so how you identify the second label ? by index ?